# Replace the value in column with respect to other two columns values

Tags: r, data-processing

> ```
> Data1
>   A     B      C 
>   a     1     a,b
>   b     6     c,b
>   c     5     b,c
>   d     3     a,d
> ```

So now i want to make new column "D"

where it replace values as per column A and B values, for example.

> ```
>   C      D
>  a,b    1,6
>  c,b    5,6
>  b,c    6,5
>  a,d    1,3
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `chartr`.  Create the `old` and `new` arguments for `chartr` by `paste`ing the `key/value` columns i.e. 'A' and 'B' and use `x` as the 'C' column to replace the substring in 'C' that matches with 'A' to that of 'B'

```
Data1$D <- with(Data1, chartr(paste(A,collapse=""), paste(B,collapse=""), C))
Data1$D
#[1] "1,6" "5,6" "6,5" "1,3"
```

#### Update

This should also work if the 'x' is from a different dataset

```
with(Data1, chartr(paste(A,collapse=""), paste(B,collapse=""), Data2$Col1))
#[1] "1,5" "6,3" "1,1" "1,5"
```

#### data

```
Data1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), B = c(1L, 6L, 5L, 3L
), C = c("a,b", "c,b", "b,c", "a,d")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Data2 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("a,c", "b,d", "a,a", "a,c"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: now in case our A and B are in Same table but our C is in Different table so is this possible to make column D as per above condition???

Comment: Because here i mansion  Data1 after  with( ) but when i try with two tables which tables name put at this place ???

Comment: with(iab, chartr(paste(iab$id,collapse=""), paste(iab$iab_id,collapse=""), Fin_Cat$category))                                                                            **Error** in chartr(paste(iab$id, collapse = ""), paste(iab$iab_id, collapse = ""),  : 
  decreasing range specification ('2-1')

Comment: still same error  **decreasing range specification ('2-1')**

Comment: @sahildesai without a reproducible example, it is difficult to know the source of error

Comment: @sahildesai  So your column must be a list.

Comment: yup for ex. c("abc","xyz")

Comment: solution is  Fin=lapply(Fin, function(x)  a[match(x,b)])